# C - What library (.so file) is the c function open() in, and how would I find that out for an arbitrary function?

Tags: c, file, dlsym

How can I find the library where the function open() is? Like, the name of the actual "xxxxxx.so" file that contains that function? Also, is there a place I could typically get this information for other functions?

Comment: The nm command will search an object file and list the names of entry points.  You can start with that.  open() is a syscall - the declaration and entry point are in libc.so.[nnnn].  See the syscall() man page here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html

Comment: Do you need the filename or just a handle for `dlsym`? Maybe have a look at `RTLD_DEFAULT` and `RTLD_NEXT`.

Comment: XY problem anyone? Why do you need that?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. And I do need it for dlsym, and I have it using RTLD_NEXT, but I wanted to try it with dlopen.

Comment: Just for the sake of trying it for getting familiar with `dlopen`/`dlsym`? I mean, is a hard-coded location OK (platform-specific, look into `/lib/...` or `/lib64/...`) The general case will be impossible, I think (and sounds like an XY problem/design-flaw -- if you use `RTLD_NEXT`, you usually don't care about the file name, and if you used `dlopen` but forgot the filename, then this is the problem). E.g. under Linux, you can load a library, delete (unlink) the file and the handler remains valid (but there is no file name).

Comment: I just wanted to see if I could get the same result with dlopen. Also, I realized I didn't know how to find the library a given function was in, which was required for dlopen, so rather than ask for a specific solution to my problem, I thought I'd try to learn something instead :)

Answer (score 0):

> I didn't know how to find the library a given function was in, which
>   was required for dlopen

Knowing the library is not required for [`dlopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlopen.html):

> If *file* is a null pointer, *dlopen*() shall return a
>   global symbol table handle for the currently running process image.
>   This symbol table handle shall provide access to the symbols from an
>   ordered set of executable object files consisting of the original
>   program image file, any executable object files loaded at program
>   start-up as specified by that process file (for example, shared
>   libraries), and the set of executable object files loaded using
>   *dlopen*() operations with the RTLD_GLOBAL flag. …

But if you really want to know:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main()
{
    // We don't need to know the library for dlopen():
    void *handle = dlopen(NULL, RTLD_NOW);
    if (!handle) puts(dlerror()), exit(1);
    void *p = dlsym(handle, "open");
    char *s = dlerror();
    if (s) puts(s), exit(1);
    printf("open = %p\n", p);

    // But we can find the library with a Glibc extension:
    Dl_info info;
    if (dladdr(p, &info))
        printf("%s contains %s\n", info.dli_fname, info.dli_sname);
}
```